# UnicodeEncodeError while using h5 file in Python vs

Tags: python, visual-studio, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, h5py

I have a problem while reading h5 files which contain weights values(from models in tf). When I run the program I get this: **UnicodeEncodeError: Message='mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character.**
I tried opening the files but they had weird symbols in them.
Do I need to download the files again or is there a way to fix it?
Please, I'd be grateful if you could help!!
I need to fix it till tomorrow!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this error message from TF? How did you "open" the file to see the weird symbols? HDF5 is a binary format so you need to use HDFViewer (or another tool). Easiest fix is downloading again. Be sure to use a transfer protocol that supports binary formats. If you continue to have problems, update your question with more details.

Comment: please share more details, if you are using google collab then this problem should not be there. In case you are using a windows machine, make sure you use ' before the path of the file.